# Normalization in R

Tags: r

```
ID_REF           GSM133971          GSM133972               GSM13397
244901_at   5.95461158752441E+001   1.88836498260498E+001   1.9821
244902_at   7.25400314331055E+001   2.65250205993652E+001   1.9532
244903_at   2.23291015625000E+002   1.78133636474609E+002   5.3816
244904_at   3.65505447387695E+001   3.04016351699829E+000   6.8046
244905_at   4.07523269653320E+001   2.58869285583496E+001   1.1808
244906_at   1.50184860229492E+002   5.39840278625488E+001   4.1491
244907_at   2.65190029144287E+001   1.39808797836304E+000   2.0866
244908_at   3.50156021118164E+000   1.05003893375397E+000   4.5765
```

In the above dataset the first two columns are MAS5.0 normalized and the last column is RMA normalized. Would it be be possible to denormalize the dataset so that I can perform RMA normaliztion throughout ? The last column was from a different experiment which I needed to append. SO the normaliztions are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no. Take a simple normalisation procedure where we have a mean of zero:

```
#Two data sets 
 c(1, 2, 3)
 c(4, 5, 6)
```

The normalised data for both data sets is:

```
 c(-1, 0, 1)
```

I realise that MAS5.0 is a lot more complicated, but the same concept applies.

Comment: Would it be allright to work with the two different normalizations in a single datset ?

Comment: It depends on what you are doing. For example, you can't just combine the datasets.